# Eclipse WindowBuilder error

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, windowbuilder

When i try to make a Swing Application window using WindowBuilder in Eclipse i get the following error:

> This is not a GUI class and can't be edited graphically
>
> The parser parsed the compilation unit, but can't identify any GUI
>   toolkit.
>
> Possible reasons:
>
> You open a compilation unit without any GUI, such as an empty class,
>   data bean, etc.  Classpath of project is not valid, does not include
>   all required toolkit libraries.  You attempt to open UI for toolkit,
>   support for which is not installed in WindowBuilder.  Use button Show
>   UI Toolkits to install new toolkit.

I used New>Other>WindowBuilder>Swing Designer>Application Window

This is the code it generates, not really much:

```
package com.sydcul.malucraft;



public class LoginForm {

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your installation. my wizard creates some more code.

Comment: Yeah, think so. I am on an other computer and it works great the same way now.